# When stretching website my img is getting under the h1 tag? How can I overcome this scenario so that image gets stick to the right side of the page

Tags: html

While stretching my website my `.png` file is getting under the h1 tag? I want to fix the image on the right side while I stretch so it can be mobile responsive.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 


 href=" 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
[![this image is a png image][1]][1]crossorigin="anonymous">




<title>Hello, world!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="/map.png" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick an image to the right side of an HTML page, you can use the style attribute and set the value of the float property to right.

`<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" style="float: right;">`

Comment: using bootstrap here.

Comment: i want it to be responsive. as when i stretch this element it shouldn't come below the hello world which is a h1 tag, so how can i overcome this? using bootstrap here. I want it to be mobile responsive and tablet responsive too.